# Using Max in a Having SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have SQL query that gives me the following sample data:

```
Name    |  Address   |  Seq_No  |
Name1      Add1            6
Name1      Add1            6
Name1      Add1            6
Name1      Add1            5
Name1      Add1            5
Name1      Add1            6
Name2      Add2            2
Name2      Add2            1
Name2      Add2            2
Name2      Add2            2
Name2      Add2            1
```

I want to be able to pull out of the result set the data where the SEQ_No is the Maximum value

I have tried using a HAVING at the end of the query:

```
HAVING SEQ_no=MAX(seq_no)
```

But that doesn't work, if I use

```
HAVING SEQ_no=6
```

then obviously this pulls out the data where seq_no=6, what am I doing wrong with the MAX?

Comment: Please place you SQL query here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Rank() function to  assign ranking based on seq and then filter by Rank=1
LIKE 
Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY clnt_name,cmpadd.add_1 ORDER BY hraptvpd.seq_no DESC) AS RNK 
After that you can filter on where RNK =1

I tried editing your query, if there is any error please sort it out

```
select
 hgmclent.clnt_name 
,cmpadd.add_1
,cmpadd.add_2
,cmpadd.add_3
,hgmprty1.post_code
,hgmprty1.prty_id
,hraptvpd.seq_no
,vd_prd
,void_cd
,void_desr
,st_date
,seq_no
,end_date
,est_avldt
,lst_revn,
Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY clnt_name,cmpadd.add_1 ORDER BY hraptvpd.seq_no DESC) AS RNK
 from hgmprty1
join hratency on prty_ref=prty_id
join hrartamt on hrartamt.rent_acc_no=hratency.rent_acc_no
join hracracr on hracracr.rent_acc_no=hrartamt.rent_acc_no
join hgmclent on hgmclent.client_no=hracracr.clnt_no
join cmpadd on cmpadd.add_id=hgmprty1.add_cd
JOIN hraptvpd WITH (nolock) ON  hraptvpd.prty_ref=hgmprty1.prty_id
JOIN hraptvps on hraptvps.prty_ref=hraptvpd.prty_ref AND seq_no=vd_prd
where
tency_end_dt is NULL AND
prim_clnt_yn=1
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need HAVING here just WHERE:

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE SEQ_no=(SELECT MAX(SEQ_no) FROM T)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where Seq_No  >=all(select Seq_No  from table);
```